# Moment-generating Function of a Continuous R.V. whose P.D.F is 1 from (0, 1)

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I have been working on this problem for a few hours now and I feel I am missing something simple. The problem is to find the moment-generating function of a continuous random variable whose probability density function is defined as:

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&1 && 0 < x < 1\\
&0 && \mbox{elsewhere}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

I know that the moment-generating function for a continuous random variable is given by:

$$
M_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\cdot f(x)dx
$$

So for the problem, the moment-generating function should be:

$$
M_X(t) = 1\cdot \int_0^1 e^{tx}dx = {{e^{tx}}\over{t}} \left|\begin{aligned} 1\\ 0\end{aligned}\right. = {{e^t-1}\over{t}}
$$

However, the answer is given as:

$$
M_X(t) = {{2e^t}\over{3-e^t}}
$$

I'm not exactly sure how they arrived at this answer, whether there is a simple algebraic manipulation I've overlooked or I've just completely forgotten how to integrate. Any tips pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) agrees with you. Furthermore, since $e^{tx}\cdot f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ and $t$ we must have that $M_X(t)\geq 0$. This surely doesn't hold if $M_X(t)=2e^t/(3-e^t)$.

Comment: It seems that it might just have been a typo in the book then. Thank you very much for the reassurance, and the alternate way of thinking about the problem; you've helped me greatly!